# When ImageMagic resize 200% text in psd file to png is too vague, why? it is vector graphics

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, psd

[image: 200% comparison of imagemagic export from psd and open photoshop to resize]

I use the command: convert 1.psd[13] -resize 200% 1.png, the result quality is so bad...Although my English is so bad, but please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use [`-density`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#density) not `-resize` for this task. [See *Pointsize, Density and the Actual Font Size* usage examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#pointsize).

```
convert -density 200 1.psd[13] 1.png
```

Comment: I had watched the link you send,but i still could not find the result that i want...Maybe I didn't clarify the problem, In simple terms, how to nondestructive amplification PSD file(1.psd[13] to 1.png)？Can you tell me? 谢谢！